# PID Tuning for 6 degree of freedom robot with ROS

Tags: control-systems, pid

I'd like to start by saying that I'm pretty clueless about controllers, control theory, or really anything to do with this subject. I'm a programmer, but I'm part of a project involving a 6 degree of freedom robotic arm with Dynamixel MX-106 motors.

I've created a PID controller for each motor of the robot, using C++ and ROS. (One ROS node is the PID controller, it reads positions from another node and calculates the appropriate torque to apply based on that, while another reads torques and applies them, while publishing positions for each of the motors).

How can I go about tuning this controller? Manual tuning has not been effective, and I have spent days trying to plug this setup into the MatLab PID autotuner with no results.

I've also tried writing a program that applies 1000 different torques, and records the torque and position data in real time. I tried calculating a transfer function from this data, then doing autotuning this way- but MatLab's transfer function estimation was so inaccurate it was basically useless.

I can upload actual code snippets when I go into work if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us much on your application.

How many actuators do you have ? Given that this is a 6 degree of freedom controller I expect that you have 6 different actuators. Or maybe there are ways to have 6 degrees of freedom with less than 6 actuators?

If the output variables are 100% uncoupled and if your model is approximately linear you should have 6 transfer functions. Do you have these transfer functions ? Can you derive them from the mechanical equations ?

You can also perform black-box modeling and determine each transfer functions by applying a step on each motor and analyzing the behavior of each outputs.

Once, you have found the transfer functions, use something like the pidTuner app in Matlab or Simulink to find appropriate gains for each controller. Instead of using the Matlab toolbox, have you tried fitting an order-1 or order-2 transfer function that fits the measured data? A lowpass order-1 transfer function is pretty easy to fit, you don't know a toolbox for that.

However, I expect that your system is highly-coupled, can you give us more information?

What's ROS ? What's the latency between the readings and the actual actuation of the motor?

Comment: This is halfway between a comment and an answer, I'll edit the post as soon as the OP gives us more info.

Comment: Yes, there are 6 actuators and the output variables are uncoupled(if I understand what this means correctly, one actuator does not depend on any information from the other). How would I go about black-box modeling? I tried getting a transfer function from steps, but I think I did it incorrectly/misunderstand what that actually means. ROS is the Robot Operating System, essentially a way to send information between different programs and processes easily for robotics. There is latency, but its very low. I'm not sure how to calculate it, as I come from a software-only background

Comment: By coupling I mean this : 

If one actuator controls only one output variable and has zero effect on other output variables then the system is uncoupled. Otherwise, there is some coupling.

As for latency : You know that latency is a killer right? How low is it? 10 µs, 1 ms, 10 ms?